# Is it possible to just have 'SELECT' clause with subqueries WITHOUT 'FROM' clause?

Tags: sql

Is it possible to have the following SQL form:

```
SELECT
    (
        (SUBQUERY1) -
        (SUBQUERY2)
    )
```

Assume that these two subqueries are correct. It looks wired to me since there is no FROM in the first query.

Thanks!

Just a simple example from a university class:

Given relations:

- Students (id, gpa) where `id` is the key
- Enrolls (id, number, term) where all three attributes make up the key

Find the difference between the average GPA of the students who take Class1 and that of the students who take Class2. Assume that there are students who took either more than once.

Is the following SQL query OK?

```
SELECT
    (SELECT AVG(gpa)
     FROM Students
     WHERE id IN (SELECT id
                  FROM Enrolls
                  WHERE number = "CLASS1")
    )
    -
    (SELECT AVG(gpa)
     FROM Students
     WHERE id IN (SELECT id
                  FROM Enrolls
                  WHERE number = "CLASS2")
    )
```

Comment: Each subquery can return only one row of one field and they will have no relationship to eachother besides what relationship may be conferred by either the single row/field in the table, or the WHERE clause in each SELECT. So... yes, but there's probably a better way to solve whatever problem it might be used to solve.

Comment: Any specific DBMS? There are already a number of SO Q&A's on this topic that may be helpful to you, but it would be better if you could narrow the question down a bit, maybe with a somewhat more real-world example.

Comment: That depends on the database.  Some databases require a `from` clause and some do not.

Comment: Just updated the question with a specific question.

Comment: In IT, the answer that is pretty much as universal as "42" is "It depends".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on the DBMS you use. On SQL Server, this is valid. On Oracle, a `SELECT` needs to have a `FROM`, but you can use `dual` which is a readonly one row one column table provided by the system if your `SELECT` works without a `FROM` clause (like in your example) and only needs the `FROM` clause to make the SQL parser happy.

Comment: MySQL also allows it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to have this construct. Consider this example (`MySQL`)

```
mysql> select ((select length('abcde')) - (select length('xyz')));

+-----------------------------------------------------+
| ((select length('abcde')) - (select length('xyz'))) |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                   2 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as the subqueries return one value each.

Compare:

```
Select (select 1), (select 2)
```

or

```
Select (1), (2)
```

, both of which work, 
to:

```
Select (select 1, 3), (select 2, 5)
```

which returns the following error in SQL Server:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Only one expression can be
>   specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with
>   EXISTS.